# How do I connect to Cassandra DB from PHP?

Tags: cassandra, thrift

I am new to cassandra. I would like to know how can I connect to a Cassandra DB from PHP. I am looking to use this for a very high traffic website. Will thrift be the best option? Or can I connect using some other method efficiently?

Kindly let me know.

Comment: Best option is to use official driver https://github.com/datastax/php-driver :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [DataStax Cassandra PHP Driver](https://github.com/datastax/php-driver).  You should not use thrift.